# Consuming SharePoint RSS feeds in another SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-server, rss

In a real life scenario, I have two different SharePoint servers, **contoso1** & **contoso2**, from contoso1 I'm sending out Rss feed subscription link and I'm trying to consume that link in a Rss Viewer web part in contoso2, what happens is that in contoso2, SharePoint treats the Rss subscription link as if it was a local link, and replaces the server name contoso1 with contoso2 in **More** link in the web part, any clues on solving this problem?